# WPF+MVVM: How to use plain old ViewModelBase when DependencyProperty is needed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

I am using a 3rd party WPF control whose MVVM support relies on dependency properties on the VM it is bound to. The sample that comes with the control uses a ViewModelBase class derived from DependencyObject so all is well.

My ViewModelBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged and for various reasons it is unrealistic to change it to DependencyObject.

My question is how do I use my ViewModels with this WPF control? I guess what I need is something like "embedding a dependencyobject" or "plugging dependency properties" in a plain old ViewModel.

By the way my MVVM application is interface based, i.e. everywhere SomeViewModel is ISomeViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a properly designed *control* shouldn't require binding to a `DependencyProperty`, as a DP can bind to any property without issue.  As such, I'd revisit whether this is truly a bug in the control implementation first, and correct that.

However, if you must do this, realize you're going to violate MVVM - using `DependencyObject` within a ViewModel is, by its very nature, injecting view specific framework elements into the VM.  Once you decide you're okay with doing this, you can always have your ViewModel expose a DependencyObject as a property, and bind to a DependencyProperty defined on that DependencyObject instead of directly to your VM's property.